# Rails simple_form shorter string inside value=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have an app where one of the registration steps is to fill out a survey. The survey has questions at the top and answers as a radio buttons. I'm using `simple_form` gem to creates forms like below:

```
<%= simple_form_for :appropriateness_test_results, url: url  do |f| %>
  <% randomize_questions.each_with_index.map do |q, i| %>
    <%= f.input "[#{i}][answer]", label: "#{i+1}. #{q[:question]}", collection: q[:answers], as: :radio_buttons, wrapper_class: 'input simple-radio-buttons'%>
    <%= f.input "[#{i}][question]", as: :hidden, input_html: { value: q[:question] } %>
    <%= f.input "[#{i}][id]", as: :hidden, input_html: { value: q[:id] } %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

`randomize_questions` is an array of hashes with questions and answers.

```
randomize_questions = 
[{:id=>8, :question=>"step one: question of category1", :answers=>["Yes", "No", "Don't know"]}, 
{:id=>4, :question=>"step one: question of category4", :answers=>["Yes", "No", "Don't know"]},]
```

With the above code I think it unnecessarily renders `answers` in two places - inside `<label>Yes</label>` and `<span (...) value="Yes">`. Output from the browser console:

```
<span class="radio"><input class="radio_buttons required" type="radio" value="Yes" name="appropriateness_test_results[[0][answer]]" id="appropriateness_test_results_[0][answer]_yes">
  <label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="appropriateness_test_results_[0][answer]_yes">
    "Yes"
  </label>
</span>
```

It's not a problem when I have just `yes` or `no` option but I could imagine it will be a problem with a long answers e.g.:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vitae nisi ut ante euismod malesuada ac sit amet magna. Suspendisse scelerisque id odio non vestibulum.

I think it might cause a mess. Is there a way to have some shorter string of that `value=` instead of the full answer like now?

Comment: You could take an id instead of a full string

Comment: I could but the question is how to do so? it's not about changing `collection: q[:answers]` to `collection: q[:id]` because still, I need to display somehow those answers.

Comment: Since you store your answers in an array, you can do an `#each_with_index`, setting the value with the index and printing the string to the user

Comment: If you know how to do it based on `each_with_index` I assume you know how to pass eg. `'foo'` inside of `value=` am I right? If yes why to move such logic inside of views if I can pass some random string inside of `value=` ? Again, how to pass such random string?