# Rails manipulating `value=` data inside form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to understand (and change if possible) where the data comes from inside of `value=` when `simple_form` gem creates below HTML output:

```
<span class="radio"><input class="radio_buttons required" type="radio" value="Yes" name="appropriateness_test_results[[0][answer]]" id="appropriateness_test_results_[0][answer]_yes">
  <label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="appropriateness_test_results_[0][answer]_yes">
    "Yes"
  </label>
</span>
```

I want to change `value="Yes"` to eg. `'1'` - is it possible to manipulate this `value=` ? I use simple_form gem to creates form, code below:

```
<%= simple_form_for :appropriateness_test_results, url: url  do |f| %>
  <% randomize_questions.each_with_index.map do |q, i| %>
    <%= f.input "[#{i}][answer]", label: "#{i+1}. #{q[:question]}", collection: q[:answers], as: :radio_buttons, wrapper_class: 'input simple-radio-buttons'%>
    <%= f.input "[#{i}][question]", as: :hidden, input_html: { value: q[:question] } %>
    <%= f.input "[#{i}][id]", as: :hidden, input_html: { value: q[:id] } %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

I have described this problem in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67674024/rails-simple-form-shorter-string-inside-value). Any, really ANY suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: The format for `collection` is `[['value','display value']]` when you pass an `Array` of `['Yes','No',"Don't know"]` it will use these values for both options. You could change this to something like `collection: q[:answers].map.with_index(1) {|a,i| [i.to_s,a] }`

Comment: Actually it should be opposite inside of `map.with_index` -  `q[:answers].map.with_index { |a, i| [a.to_s, i] }` but generally you're right! god bless you good man! please post your answer so I can mark it as solved. It would be super nice if you explained where/how you found it because I couldn't find it even in gem source file

Comment: You are right I apologize as for where [Here](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form#collections) second example and the paragraph above it